# Why am I getting an "invalid data type" error in this sample mpi broadcast program?

Tags: mpi, openmpi

*After making the changes mentioned in the comments, not getting any output.*

I'm new to MPI. If I run it with more than two processes I get two additional lines on my console saying:

1- more process has sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal

2- Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages.

What am I doing wrong?
This is the complete output on my terminal:

> *** An error occurred in MPI_Bcast
>
> *** reported by process [4248174593,1]
>
> *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
>
> *** MPI_ERR_TYPE: invalid datatype
>
> *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
>
> ***    and potentially your MPI job)
>
> 1 more process has sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / 
>   mpi_errors_are_fatal Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0
>   to see all help / error messages

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int server = 0;
    const int source = server;
    float* array = (float*)NULL;
    int length;
    int num_procs, my_rank, mpi_error_code;
    int index;

    mpi_error_code = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    mpi_error_code = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    mpi_error_code = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);

    /*input, allocate, initialize on server only*/
    if(my_rank == server){
      scanf("%d", &length);
      array = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) * length);
      for(index = 0; index < length; index++){
          array[index] = 0.0;
      }
    }
    /*broadcast, output on all processes*/
    if(num_procs > 1){
      mpi_error_code = MPI_Bcast(&length, 1, MPI_INT, source, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      if(my_rank != server){
        array = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) * length);
      }
      mpi_error_code = MPI_Bcast(array, length, MPI_INT, source, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      printf("%d: broadcast length = %d\n", my_rank, length);
    }

    mpi_error_code = MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: In C, the types are `MPI_INT`, `MPI_DOUBLE`, `MPI_FLOAT`, etc; in Fortran they're `MPI_INTEGER`, `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION`, `MPI_REAL`, and so on.  You want to be using `MPI_INT`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, changed the two MPI_INTEGER parameters to MPI_INT.
But now, It seems I've ran into a new problem. I don't get any errors, but the  programs won't print the output and seems to be stock in an infinite loop or something.

Comment: The code is correct and works for me. Are you running on more than one node? If so, then you should be aware that Open MPI is a bit greedy when it comes to utilising the available network interfaces and might get stuck with certain configurations. Please run `ifconfig` on the nodes and provide the output.

Comment: @HristoIliev: I'm running it on just one node(It's my laptop, Ubuntu 16.04 and openmpi-1.10.2). 
I don't get any output. the output should be similar to this, when running with 4 processes: 
0 : broadcast length = 16777216

1 : broadcast length = 16777216    

2 : broadcast length = 16777216    

3 : broadcast length = 16777216

Comment: It's probably a dumb question to ask, but since your program is reading interactively the array length initially, do you type that `16777216` before it hangs? What happens when you input a smaller length, e.g. 4?

Comment: @HristoIliev: I'm using this manual, and the example begins at page 57:
[link](http://www.linuxclustersinstitute.org/workshops/files/sipe_mpi.pdf)
in the tutorial, the authors didn't write any input, after you mentioned typing the input, It's working! 
Did the authors forget writing the input in the manual?

Comment: Only the author(s) could truly answer that question. Perhaps someone mixed up several codes. The Fortran version does read the input from a file and probably the intention was for the C code to do the same. The entire tutorial is pretty sloppy though and full of mistakes like using `MPI_INT` in Fortran and `MPI_INTEGER` in C code. Also, giving user variables the reserved `mpi_` prefix is a really bad programming style.